How can I use "case when" in DuckDB's relational API?
Say I have
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 'd': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
 'sales': [1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2]}

My ultimate goal for now is to be able to translate
import duckdb
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
duckdb.sql("""
select *, case when count(sales) over w then sum(sales) over w else null end as rolling_sales
from df
window w as (partition by id order by d rows between 1 preceding and current row)
""")

I've got as far as:
rel = duckdb.table("df")
rel.sum(
    "sales",
    projected_columns="*",
    window_spec="over (partition by id order by d rows between 1 preceding and current row) as rolling_sales",
)

which I think is a lot more readable than a huge SQL string
But how do I get the case when then part in there? I've looked at https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/relational_api.html and there's no mention of "case"

I'm not sure it's the best way to approach it, and I think just writing plain SQL (or using polars API) will be more readable, but you can do something like this:
rel = rel.count(
    "*",
    projected_columns="*",
    window_spec="over (partition by id order by d rows between 1 preceding and current row) as rolling_sale",
)
rel = rel.select(
    "* exclude(rolling_sale), case when rolling_sale then sales else null end as rolling_sale"
)
rel = rel.sum(
    "rolling_sale",
    projected_columns="* exclude(rolling_sale)",
    window_spec="over (partition by id order by d rows between 1 preceding and current row) as rolling_sale",
)

┌───────┬───────┬───────┬──────────────┐
│  id   │   d   │ sales │ rolling_sale │
│ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │    int128    │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼──────────────┤
│     1 │     1 │     1 │            1 │
│     1 │     2 │     4 │            5 │
│     1 │     3 │     2 │            6 │
│     2 │     1 │     3 │            3 │
│     2 │     2 │     1 │            4 │
│     2 │     3 │     2 │            3 │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴──────────────┘

